# Created time greater than or equal to

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query which will show all records greater than or equal to a 2013-08-01.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM v_itdept_allcases
WHERE `Created Time` >= '2013-08-01';
```

The query returns dates between `30-06-2006` and `23-09-2013`.

Not quite sure what else to try as I have tried several variations with no luck.

Gary

Comment: Your first mentioned format is YYYY-MM-DD (I assume) but you seem to be comparing to records of the form DD-MM-YYYY, my guess is that you're dealing with a conflict of formats.

Comment: What data type has your column?

Comment: what is the type of the `Created Time` column? If it's **NOT** a mysql date/datetime field, then you're doing string comparisons, and all bets are off.

Comment: Also, including spaces in column names WILL DRIVE YOU MAD

Comment: what is the type of your `Created Time` field?

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, you're probably hitting a format or string comparison issue.  I would suggest converting to an easily comparable monotonic format, such as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`, when then can be arithmetically modified.  You are correct that you shouldn't need to do that, but it's a reasonably bulletproof solution.